# could not find config.h file (ssh source codes)

Tags: c, openssh

I am exploring SSH source codes that I cloned from github repo (https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable.git). I want to compile a file but it includes a `<config.h>` header file that doesn't exist in cloned directory. How can I fix this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the INSTALL docs.

Answer (score 4):

[openssh-portable/configure.ac#L21](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/a1f78e08bdb3eaa88603ba3c6e01de7c8671e28a/configure.ac#L21):

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
```

`config.h` is created by `autoconf` utility program (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Configuration-Headers.html)). You need to run

```sh
autoreconf
./configure
```

to configure your build env before you run `make` command.

Check out the official [INSTALL](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/INSTALL) and [README.md](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/README.md) for more information.